# Can I use payment gateways like Razorpay or Paypal in my React Native app?

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, payment-gateway

I am developing a native app in React Native app which will be published on Play Store and Apple App Store. I want to know if I can integrate a 3rd party payment gateway like Paypal rather than using Google Play in App Billing System?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You need to use Apple Pay or Google Pay in order to be accepted into the stores.

[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10281818?hl=en-GB#:~:text=All%20apps%20are%20required%20to,not%20limited%20to%2C%20app%20removals](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10281818?hl=en-GB#:%7E:text=All%20apps%20are%20required%20to,not%20limited%20to%2C%20app%20removals).

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase